# If using QString after being `std::move`d defined?

Tags: c++, qt, move-semantics

Consider following pattern, stripped  of details for simplicity:

```
 QString str  = /* expression */
 /* some actions with str */
 foo(std::move(str));

 str =  /* expression */
 /* some actions with str */
 foo(std::move(str));
```

Does reuse of `str` yield defined behaviour in Qt 4.8.6? Qt 5.x?

Comment: After `std::move`, a variable is suitable for reassignment or destruction.  So reassigning `str` to the result of an expression ought to be legit.

Comment: @Eljay thanks , I guess I just had a brainfart toward the end of Friday after reading a lot of bad code with UBs, it wasn't my code to begin with

Comment: Qt 4 didn’t implement move’s at all, so a std::move on a Qt 4 QString would just (shallow) copy.

Comment: @André shallow copy on pimpl class still gives certain speedup according to bench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A move operation leaves the moved-from object in a "valid but unspecified state":

> 16.5.5.16 Moved-from state of library types [lib.types.movedfrom]
>
> Objects of types defined in the C ++ standard library may be moved
> from. Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly
> generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall
> be placed in a valid but unspecified state.

This statement, from the C++ standard, refers to the classes from the C++ library, as noted. However, it is a fairly easy bet that the Qt library seeks to comply to the same standards here, and this applies to the Qt library as well. It's a very safe bet to make (and it happens to be true, too).

"Valid but unspecified" state means that the moved-from object is still a valid, well-formed object. Because it's unspecified you have no guarantees, whatsoever, that if you call its `size()` method that you'll get any particular value. It could be 0 (probably), or it could be something else. However, since it's a valid object, whatever you get from a `size()` of a moved-from `QString`, if you then proceed and check what's in the string, you'll see the same exact number of character in there.

And, since it's a valid `QString` object you are free to completely replace its contents by assigning something to it, leaving the object is a fully-specified, valid state.